# How to access a Private Google Fusion table on a website that is live to display data on a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Fusion table that I am using to display locations on a Google Map on my website via the Google Maps API. Currently the Fusion table is Public. I would like to make the Google Fusion table Private to protect the data in the table. I've tried doing this and as soon as the table is private the data will no longer display on the map on my website.

I've done some extensive research on whether or not it's possible to use a private Google Fusion table like I described above. A few other forums mentioned that if you have a Google Premium Account you can plug in your clientID to the protected map layer feature in the Google fusion table. This did not work for me.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: My 10 seconds "extensive research" lead me to this first Google result: ***Private** - If you leave your table as Private, only the people you have specifically invited will have access to your table. Embedded visualizations and Google Earth network links will not be able to access the data.* - https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171221?hl=en

Comment: Thanks... I also found that link during the first 10 seconds of my extensive research. No luck from that forum though.

Comment: Well... it says what it says... If it's private, you can't access it. If you really want to make sure the data stays private, you'd better import your table contents to a database and grab the data from there.

Comment: As I mentioned I found a few forums where people highlighted a way to do it with the protected map layer. It wasn't well documented when I tried it I had no luck. But apparently some people have figured it out. That's why I'm here asking this question...

Comment: Also we are currently setting up the database. We plan to migrate off the fusion table soon but for the time being we don't want our data public.

Comment: Maybe then. But when official docs say you can't, usually you can't. At least not in a documented way. You could duplicate your table to a private one and reduce the public table to some sample data so that you can continue development (if that's what you are doing), until you have your db ready.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google decided deprecate Fusion Table Layer in Google Maps JavaScript API

> The Fusion Tables Layer in the Maps JavaScript API is deprecated as of December 3, 2018. The Fusion Tables Layer will be completely turned off on December 3, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#335

You should consider alternatives for your application.